# MySQL stored procedure call from ASP.NET 2 throws Use Procedure bodies exception

Tags: asp.net, mysql, exception, stored-procedures, parameters

Hi I have the following scenario. I am calling stored procedures to MySQL 5.x from my .NET 2 application. All stored procedures have parameters and they work fine with the exception of two which throw the following exception (only when deployed to production):

"When calling stored procedure and 'Use Procedure bodies' is false, all parameters must have their type explicitly set.

This only occurs on the "production" environment. On my development machine, everything works fine in all cases.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance,
Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK solved. I was passing DBNULL.Value as a parameter which it did not like apparently.

Answer (score 1):

The database account the application code is using may not have select permissions on mysql.proc. Provide the select permissions to the database account.

[This](http://markcordell.blogspot.com/2008/12/calling-mysql-stored-procedures-from-c.html) blog post explains the reason in detail.