# Calling a stored procedure in mysql from .NET throws error - all parameters must have their type explicitly set

Tags: .net, asp.net, mysql, stored-procedures

I have a page which submits a form in my local system but in my production system when i click my submit button it just freezes with the error in my web developer toolbar saying

```
Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: When calling stored 
procedures and 'Use Procedure Bodies' is false, all parameters must have their
type explicitly set.
```

**EDIT:**

I am using `mysql.data.dll` version `5.0.7.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps?

[MySQL stored procedure call from ASP.NET 2 throws Use Procedure bodies exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081815/mysql-stored-procedure-call-from-asp-net-2-throws-use-procedure-bodies-exception)

If not it might helpfull to know which driver you use.